# Как стримить поток с tcpdump ?

Tags: потоки-данных, filestream

Хочу постримить данные tcpdump,  в поток на комп где есть wireshark .

Делал ли кто нибудидь такое  ?

Comment: В wireshark есть такая вещь, как Remote Interfaces.

Comment: постримить? Вы просто хотите в wireshark посмотреть то, что tcpdump собирает? можно же просто сохранить в файл и потом скачать этот файл.

Comment: не это не катит  каждый раз таскать фаил с сервера , а у меня больше 100 серверов

Comment: автоматизация - наше все!. делаете скрипт, который умеет запустить tcpdump на удаленном сервере и потом перекачать локально pcap файл с открытием в wireshark.

Comment: задача то не фаилы  гонять, а стримм создать .

Comment: https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/23609/remote-capture-via-ssh-and-pipe

Comment: @xmaster83 укажите требования типа "у меня больше 100 серверов" прямо в вопросе (то что имеет смысл если вывод tcpdump со 100 машин хотите собирать, может быть перебор если вам один раз вывод tcpdump с удалённого сервера забрать). Не пробовали tshark запустить вместо tcpdump + wireshark?

Comment: так не одновременно  же со  100 машин  смотреть, просто чтоб не таскать фаилы туда сюда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашёл на  Микротике решение и на Циске   если кому надо то вот ссылки .

http://blog.mistifiks.ru/2015/06/mikrotik-tcpdump-wireshark.html

http://avz.org.ua/wp/2009/09/14/catalyst-port-mirroring/

Comment: Не очень хорошие решения - там же предлагают настроить чтобы пакеты зеркалировались постоянно. Для 100 серверов вы всю сеть забьете.

Comment: [Ответы-ссылки следует избегать](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1805/23044). Упомяните суть решения прямо в ответе.

Comment: В микротике вроде настраиваеться  фильтр , а у тебя есть другие решения  ?? wireshark не собираеться с версией удаллённых интерфейсов